# webkit animation play state hover not detected while transformX

Tags: css, webkit, transform, css-animations, transition

I am trying to pause the animation(which is a CSS transformY) state on hover but the hover is **not evenly detected** accross the transform range(i observed it is properly detected in the initial range and after the transform ends)
This is the code(i simplified it to minimum for posting) :

```html
    <html>
         <head>
          <style>
           .member{
               height:50px;
               width:50px;
               margin:30px;
               border-radius:50%;
               border:1px solid #AAAAAA;
               background-color:black;
               transition:all 0.3s ease;
               -moz-animation-name: dropHeader;
               -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
               -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
               -moz-animation-duration: 6s;
               
        
           -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
           -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
           -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
           -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    
           animation-name: dropHeader;
           animation-iteration-count: 1;
           animation-timing-function: ease-in;
           animation-duration: 6s;
       }
       @-moz-keyframes dropHeader {
           0% {
               -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
           }
           100% {
               -moz-transform: translateY(0);
           }
       }
       @-webkit-keyframes dropHeader {
           0% {
               -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
           }
           100% {
               -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
           }
       }
       @keyframes dropHeader {
           0% {
               transform: translateX(200px);
           }
           100% {
               transform: translateX(0);
           }
       }
    
       .member:hover{
           border:3px solid #ffffff; 
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #7ec0ee;
           -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="member">
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the thing, i couldn't figure out the exact reason but these are all the things i tried and failed and then succeeded (in order) :
1. Removing -webkit
2. using jquery mouseover and mouseout integrated with css animationstates "running" and pause.
3. Then, i observed that after one hover if i click multiple times somewhere else on the webapage and then hover, it worked! Which gave me a hint to the direction of introducing multiple such divs and it totally works fine now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "introducing multiple such divs". Could you give us an example?